# How to update Magento 2.2.5 to Magento 2.3.1? possible issues?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, upgrade, magento2.3, magento-upgrade

I wanted to know is it possible to update Magento from 2.2.5 to 2.3.1? Or what is a solution to update all Magento 2.2.5 stores to Magento 2.3.1? If we will update it then what are the challenges for that we have to be prepared?

Please let me know if there any solution for this or not.
REF - [How to Upgrade magento version from 2.2.X to 2.3.0?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251778/how-to-upgrade-magento-version-from-2-2-x-to-2-3-0)

Comment: refer [this](https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/upgrading-to-the-pre-release-of-magento-2-3-0.html) link, you will get an idea how to do this

Comment: Thanks but this is not stable. Not found any issue list.

Comment: You are right magento 2.3 is not stable now, it will release soon check issues list of [2.3](https://github.com/magento/magento2/milestones) and [filters](https://github.com/magento/magento2/milestones/Release:%202.3.1)

Comment: I got error `Conclusion: don't install symfony/console` & `magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/framework 102.0.0` when upgrade via composer.

Answer (score 1):

For Upgrade Magento 2.2.* to Magento 2.3.0,
you can easily upgrade using Magento command line,

You need to follow four steps to upgrade from older version to latest version Magento 2.3

**`For upgrade to Magento 2.3 You must required PHP 7.1.3+ or PHP 7.2.`**

You can't simply upgrade using Composer update command only.

Check links for step by step Upgrade Magento,  [Upgrade Magento 2.2 to Magento 2.3.0](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/upgrade-magento-2-2-to-magento-2-3-version/)

Hope you will be helpful above steps.

Answer (score 0):

Some dependencies in `composer.json` need to be updated for Magento 2.3.0 before running `composer update`.  This is a side effect of adding support for PHP 7.2 and dropping support for PHP 7.0.

The full upgrade steps (and a script to ease the process) are documented [on the Magento website](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html).