# How to Upgrade magento version from 2.2.X to 2.3.0?

Tags: magento2.3.0

I have tried using bellow command but getting errors

- Command 1:

> composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 --no-update

- Command 2:

> composer update

Output:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/framework 102.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v2.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.0-BETA2|install symfony/console v2.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.0-BETA3|install symfony/console v2.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.0|install symfony/console v2.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.1|install symfony/console v2.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.2|install symfony/console v2.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.3|install symfony/console v2.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.4|install symfony/console v2.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.5|install symfony/console v2.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.6|install symfony/console v2.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.7|install symfony/console v2.8.38
```

if anyone has an idea help me..!

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you are skipping some steps.
Make sure you are specifying additional packages required :

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 --no-update
```

and remove unused packages :

```
composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
```

You are getting the error mainly because of the `fabpot/php-cs-fixer`

Also, make sure you read Magento docs

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, everything in the docs!

Answer (score 10):

Here are the steps to upgrade Magento 2.2.x to 2.3.0

Step 1: Backup code and database

Step 2:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.0 --no-update
```

Step 3:

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 --no-update
```

Step 4:

```
composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
```

Step 5:
open *composer.json* file and add this "Zend\Mvc\Controller\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/", around line 47 under psr-4 section.

Step 6:

```
composer update
```

Here is the [detailed article.](http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/upgrade-magento-version-2-2-x-2-3-0/)

Comment: For step 5: you need to do this 
"Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/",

Answer (score 9):

Here are the steps I used to **successfully update Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.0**. I have divided the steps into two parts:

**Part 1:**

- php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
- php bin/magento cache:disable
- php bin/magento maintenance:enable
- composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 --no-update
- composer update

**POSSIBLE ERROR:** You might get the following error:
 Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.9].
    - magento/magento2-base 2.3.0 requires symfony/console ~4.1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - Conclusion: don't install sebastian/phpcpd 2.0.4|don't install symfony/console v4.1.1|install symfony/console v2.8.38
    - Installation request for sebastian/phpcpd 2.0.4 -> satisfiable by sebastian/phpcpd[2.0.4].

GOTO **PART 2** FOR SOLUTION

**Part 2:**

- composer config preferred-install dist
- composer config sort-packages true
- composer config prefer-stable true
- composer require --dev friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.0 --no-update
- composer require --dev sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 --no-update
- php -r '$autoload=json_decode(file_get_contents("composer.json"), true); $autoload["autoload"]["psr-4"]["Zend\Mvc\Controller\"]= "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"; file_put_contents("composer.json", json_encode($autoload, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));'
- composer update
- rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento cache:enable
- php bin/magento maintenance:disable
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

Now, **Magento 2.2.6** should have been **SUCCESSFULLY UPGRADED** to MAGENTO **2.3.0**

Comment: works perfectly fine for me from updating 2.2.8 -> 2.3.2

Comment: i'm getting error message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'setup' (T_STRING), expecting ']' in Command line code on line 1
" when i try to run 'php -r '$autoload......'. Can you help?

Comment: If someone having the same issue like Kris Wen just add another backslash to `Zend\Mvc\Controller\` caused by escaping function of the backslash.  
  
Full example:  
  
```
php -r '$autoload=json_decode(file_get_contents("composer.json"), true); $autoload["autoload"]["psr-4"]["Zend\Mvc\Controller\\"] = "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"; file_put_contents("composer.json", json_encode($autoload, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));'
```

Comment: how to migrate data when going live?

Comment: Element 'route': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( resources ). when I execute bin/magento setup:upgrade I am stuck anyone knows?