# How to upgrade website in Magento 2.0 to Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, magento-2.0

Currently my client's website in Magento 2.0 (running on PHP-5.6). Now we want to upgrade it to Magento-2.3. Please help me in upgrading the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Upgrade your **PHP version** to 7.1.3 or 7.2.0+
2. Enable Maintenance mode
   `php bin/magento maintenance:enable`
3. Backup your `composer.json` file
4. Update the comoser.json file 
   `composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.0 --no-update`
5. Apply the updates 
   `composer update`
6. Remove the cache and generated directories
   `rm -rf var/cache/*`
   `rm -rf var/page_cache/*`
   `rm -rf generated/code/*`
7. Update the Database schema an data
   `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
   `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
8. Disable Maintenance mode
   `php bin/magento maintenance:disable`

After upgrade if you face any errors please do check your file permissions for var, pub and generated directories.

If you still face any errors check your third party modules and fix them.

Answer (score 0):

I tired upgrading from 2.3 to 2.3.1 and the process is very much broken. If you get any errors in the check phase talk to your webhost as its probably a server side issue, if you get past the check phase make sure you back everything up as this is where the process crashed for me.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Upgrade to Magento 2.3**

[https://blog.magestore.com/upgrade-magento-2-3](https://blog.magestore.com/upgrade-magento-2-3/)

Answer (score 0):

It's Very Easy. I Upgraded two websites In  Magento 2.3.1
upgrade your  PHP-5.6 to `PHP Version 7.1.28`
Open  `composer.json` file
See Below Screenshot
Put this code on line no.5 `"version": "2.3.1",`
Put this code on line no.11 `"magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.1",`
Put this code on line no.28 `"Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"`
Put a comma in last line no.27 `,`
And Run `composer update` Command and After Complete `composer update` Command run
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade; php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;`

[image]

Also You show Any error then see link
[How to Upgrade magento version from 2.2.X to 2.3.0?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251778/how-to-upgrade-magento-version-from-2-2-x-to-2-3-0)