# After upgrade to 2.3.3, got SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 when trying to run bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2.3, error, upgrade, magento-upgrade, setup-upgrade

I just upgrade to `Magento 2.3.3` from `Magento 2.2.9` following these steps `(https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251778/how-to-upgrade-magento-version-from-2-2-x-to-2-3-0)`. However, at the step

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

i got the error message below

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write;
>   duplicate key in table '#sql-1767_f1786', query was: ALTER TABLE
>   `catalog_product_entity_text` MODIFY COLUMN `value_id` int(11)  NOT
>   NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Value ID", ADD CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY
>   (`value_id`), ADD CONSTRAINT
>   `CAT_PRD_ENTT_TEXT_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`)  ON
>   DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT
>   `CAT_PRD_ENTT_TEXT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`)  ON
>   DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT
>   `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TEXT_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD
>   CONSTRAINT
>   `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TEXT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID` UNIQUE
>   KEY (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`), ADD INDEX
>   `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TEXT_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`attribute_id`), ADD INDEX
>   `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TEXT_STORE_ID` (`store_id`)

Answer (score 0):

commenting out the constraints in the following database schema file works.

**file location**: /vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/db_schema.xml

**cause**: due to csv import, all the import columns got assigned to same value_id 0

**solution**: comment out line 153-169: comment out all the constraints for 'catalog_product_entity_text' table.